# Why is it accepted that Gödel uses a self-referential statement in his incompleteness theorems?

Tags: logic, incompleteness

(I have only read second-hand about Gödel's incompleteness theorems, so I hope that there is nothing I have missed by doing that which would render my questions easily clarified.)

Gödel's first incompleteness theorem says that any consistent mathematical system is incomplete.

But the whole proof seems to depend solely on using a self-referential statement $G$ where

$G = $"G cannot be proven".

(I hope it is correct/ okay to put it like that)

It seems intuitive, however, that this statement is nonsensical.

$1.$ But then why is he allowed to use a nonsensical statement for proof?

To maybe explain at least a bit why I think it is nonsensical (if someone should not have that intuition strongly enough):

A. If we look at it as a definition of $G$, then it makes no sense to use $G$ itself in the definition of it.

This intuition could be partly the same as B.ii., but also $G$ doesn't add anything new to $G$. The self-referential aspect seems to make $G$ non-substantial.

So, $G$ seems to be without "real content".

B. Let $G_1= "G_2$ cannot be proven".

i. If $G_1$ and$ G_2 $are different, taken to be the same, this makes no sense (reminds of equivocation).

ii. If $G_1=G_2(=G)$, then we get an infinite regress.

Substitute $G_1 $for $G_2$, since it is the same thing, and we get ""$G_2$ cannot be proven" cannot be proven""= $G_1$. And do it again and we get " $G_2$ cannot be proven" cannot be proven" cannot be proven" =$ G_1.$ And so on infinitely.

In other words: "$G$ cannot be proven" can be infinitely substituted for $ G$ in "$G$ cannot be proven".

And maybe infinite regress (as a consequence) alone isn't enough to say of something that doesn't make any sense or should be discarded (we have Münchhausen Trilemma), but since $G$ intuitively also seems nonsensical (see A.), may it not be enough to discard it (/self-referential statements)?

2. Also, if we do not use $G$ (or self-referential statements in general?), we would have no proof for any of what Gödel's incompleteness theorems show, is this correct? Or: if we discard $G$, then there is still the possibility that we can have consistent and complete and decidable systems?

Someone has said that there are other proofs for it using diagonalization. But if this is true, (since I also have intuitive issues with diagonalization arguments, though somewhat less), apart from these, there are none?

Comment: "Gödel's first incompleteness theorem says that any consistent mathematical system is incomplete." No, it doesn't. If you're going to try to understand what's going on here, or in mathematics more generally, it pays to be careful to state things correctly.

Comment: "But the whole proof seems to depend solely on using a self-referential statement G where G = "G cannot be proven"." No, you've completely missed the point of the construction.

Comment: As I've said, I have only read second-hand about it. I don't intend to read all of Gödel's thesis (at the moment). So, it would be cool if you could reply with something helpful instead of just saying I have completely misunderstood.

Comment: Reading second-hand is fine, but read something good that hasn't been dumbed-down or oversimplified to the point of nonsense (and read it carefully).

Comment: The theorem says that any **sufficiently strong** consistent mathematical system is incomplete. The system has to be strong enough to do arithmetic; there are weaker systems that are complete and consistent.

Comment: Don't confuse provability with truth.

Comment: Regarding the construction: Why can't I then just say that Gödel numbers are not allowed to be made to represent self-referential sorts of statements?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with recursive definitions, if you do it properly. Eg, $T_0=0$ is a triangular number, and $T_{n+1} = T_n + n+1$ for integer $n \ge 0$.

Comment: I'm not talking about recursive definitions. And no, I didn't confuse provability with truth.

Answer (score 11):

No. A standard Gödel sentence $G$ (for a given theory $T$) is NOT *identical* to the sentence "$G$ cannot be proven) (in $T$)".

But $G$ is so constructed that it is *true if and only if*  $G$  cannot be proven in $T$.

Being materially equivalent and being identical are not the same. The difference is crucial here.

You don't need to read Gödel himself to understand that. There are many good expositions out there. For example, you could try the first three short chapters of my *Gödel Without (Too Many) Tears*, downloadable from https://www.logicmatters.net/igt

Comment: Well, if you put it like that I have no idea what the difference between material equivalence and identity should be. But I guess I will try to read on it.